# Is there a way to identify mouse leave specifically to the top in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to show a popup message for users when they are trying to leave the page by moving their mouse to the top of the window.

The issue I've faced with is that seems like internet explorer can't identify mouseleave event specifically for situation when mouse moves to the top. Instead it sets pointer coordinates clientX and clientY to '-1' in all cases of mouse moving outside the window to the top, bottom, left and right.

Need to mention that in case of moving mouse outside the window to the right (to fire the event browser should not be maximized on full screen) it sets clientY to '-1' from time to time. if you move your mouse to the left/right 20 times you will get 30% of clientY = '-1' and for rest % clientY will contain appropriate value.

I use the following code:

```
$(document).mouseleave(function(e){console.log("clientX: " + e.clientX + " clientY: " + e.clientY)});
```

Is there any way to identify mouse leave specifically on the top ? Thank you very much for any answer :)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `window.onbeforeunload` for this?

Comment: I'd recall the exact coordinates were obfuscated for a couple of years ago (since IE9?), it was some sort of security "improvement". You could try to listen `mousemove` and store the coordinates you get from that event, possibly with a small delay (mousemove coordinates are obfuscated too when mouse goes out of the page). @PaulAbbott Perhaps because when you simply move your mouse away from the browser window, `onbeforeunload` doesn't fire.

Comment: Thanks for response. The issue with `mousemove` is that IE doesn't appropriately count clientY position for it as well. Sometimes it shows 0 but sometimes value is bigger than 0 (e.g 7, 27, or even 100. This depends on the speed you moved your mouse. The quicker speed the bigger value you get). So it's hard to figure out based on this event whether customer has moved mouse to the top out of the window or just moved mouse to the top of the page (e.g moved mouse to header or page's menu)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, IE there is some Off on the value of y

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("trident")>-1){
          document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)
          document.onmousemove = getMouseXY;
          var tempX = 0;
          var tempY = 0;


          function getMouseXY(e) {
            tempX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
            tempY = (event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop);
            if(tempY <= 5)
                {
                   // your code will be here
                }
          }        
}
```